# glmnet mgaussian lambda in r

Tags: r, glmnet

I have built a multi-response regression model using glmnet package in r. I find there are two ways to extract lambda used in the training process.

```
model = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "mgaussian")
```

`model$lambda` and `model$glmnet.fit$lambda`. It turns out that `model$glmnet.fit$lambda` has one more lambda compared with `model$lambda`, say `model$glmnet.fit$lambda` is of length 100 and `model$lambda` is of length 99. Why is this the case? Thanks in advance!